# OpenCV - detecting missing coins from a tray using a live camera feed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am building a system which detects coins that are picked up from a tray. This tray will be kept in a public place. People will pick up one or more coins, but would be expected to keep them back after some time.

[image]

I would have a live stream through a webcam placed at the top. I will have a calibration step, say at the beginning of the day, that captures the initial state of the tray to be used for comparing with the live feed. A few slots might be empty to begin with, as you can see in the sample image.

I need to detect slots that had a coin initially, but are missing the same at any given point of time during the day.

I am trying out a few approaches using OpenCV:

- **SSIM difference**: I can use SSIM to find diff between my live image frame and initial state. However, a number of slots are larger than the corresponding coin sizes (e.g. top two rows). This could mean that if the coin was originally placed at the center, but was later put back to touch one of the edges, we may get a false positive.
- **Blob detection**: Alternatively, I can pre-feed (or detect) slot co-ordinates. Then do a blob detection within every slot. If a blob was present in the original state, but is missing in a camera frame, this would mean a coin has been picked up. However, accurate blob detection could be a challenge if the contrast between the coin and the tray is low.

I might also need to watch out for slight variations in lighting due to shadows of people moving around.

Any thoughts on these or any pointers on alternate approaches that can be tried out? Is there any analogous implementation that I can learn from?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks to @I.Newton's suggestion. For those who stumble upon this question and would benefit from a sample implementation, look here: https://github.com/kewats/computer-vision-samples/tree/master/image-processing/missing-coins-detection

Comment: Since the background of the coin is quite unique with Red color. You can try simple HSV based  color Filtering. i.e Find out the Tray areas & check the mean color of the Tray if it is Red then there is no coin present in it!

Comment: I have a few questions. 1) Do you only want to detect the spots where the coins go missing? 2) Do you also want each coin to be exactly placed in its slot as before?

Comment: @janu777 As of now, I just want to detect the spots where the coins go missing. I would like to highlight the corresponding slot through a red flashy rectangle drawn on the video stream. Once the coin is kept back, the flash should go away. Eventually, I would like to handle the use case where if two coins are picked up and kept back in each other's position, there should be no alerts.

Comment: @BalajiR The picture above is just for illustration. The real image may not have such a good contrast. So, I was also trying to understand if we can leverage the initial image (where all coins are surely placed on tray) to match against the live stream frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you complete control over the lighting conditions, you can use simple color thresholding to solve the problem.

First make a mask for the boxes. You can do it in multiple ways by color threshold or by using adaptive threshold or canny edge etc. I did by color threshold

[image]

Then make a mask for the coins by the same method.

[image]

Now flood fill your box mask from from the center of each of this coins. It'll retain only those which do not have the coins.

[image]

Now you can compare this with your initial mask to figure out if all the coins are present

[image]

This does not include frame subtraction. So you need not worry about different position of coin in the box. Only thing you need to make sure is the lighting conditions for making the masks. If you want to make sure the coins are returned to the same box, you should go for template matching etc which again needs effort.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and works very well for the image I provided. However, it seems I might not have sufficient contrast between the coins and the tray. Here is a more appropriate image: https://imgur.com/a/TTpse Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can try using [hough circle transform](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html). That'll do the trick. Change the parameters of the function accordingly to work for you. I don't have the code now as i used the same file for another answer.